# Preventing default form submission and calling an action instead

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, actionsupport

I have a VF Page that initially shows only an input field (lookup), with other parts of the page not rendered.  When the user enters a value and tabs out of the field, the `onchange` event calls my controller (via `actionSupport`); during the rerender, other parts of the page are conditionally rendered based on the input value. 
Here's part of my VF page:

```
<apex:actionRegion >
  <apex:outputPanel id="SalesOrderLookup"> 
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Sales Order Information" id="SalesOrderInfo">
      <apex:inputField taborderhint="5" value="{!PropertyAccount.Sales_Order__c}">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" 
                            action="{!checkSalesOrderAccount}" 
                            reRender="SalesOrderLookup" />
      </apex:inputField>
```

This is working perfectly... if the user tabs out of the field, thus firing the onchange event.  However, if the user simply presses return after keying in a value (which is likely, given that it's the only control on the page at this point), the whole page is being submitted.  This results in a whole-page refresh instead of a reRender, and the action (`{!checkSalesOrderAccount}`) never runs.  I'd like the following behavior:

- When the user presses enter, the form is not submitted.
- When the user presses enter, the `{!checkSalesOrderAccount}` action is called.

Note that there is no submit button on the page, but I assume that pressing enter is firing the form's submit action?  Which leads me to one more requirement/constraint:  all of this code is part of an `<apex:component>` which is shared by a couple of pages; the `<apex:form>` tag is in the containing page, not in the component, so I can't use the form's `onsubmit`, even if it would work for the return key.

I'm considering an `onkeypress` event handler on the inputField to watch for return being pressed.  It could cancel the keypress (which I *think* would prevent the submit), and even call `{!checkSalesOrderAccount}` if I swap my `actionSupport` for `actionFunction`.  But I wonder if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a simple javascript function to prevent a standard submitting the form with enter key and execute an `apex:actionFunction` instead:

```
<apex:form id="orderSearchForm" onkeyup="submitListener(event)">

<apex:actionFunction name="onFormSubmit" 
                     action="{!checkSalesOrderAccount}" 
                     reRender="SalesOrderLookup" />

<script>
function submitListener(e){
    var keynum = 0;
    if (window.event){
        keynum = window.event.keyCode;
    }
    else if (e.which){
        keynum = e.which;
    }

    // Here we check whether the Enter button was pressed
    if (keynum == 13){
        onFormSubmit();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is exactly the approach I'm considering (last paragraph of question), except that you use keyup v. keypress (which I wasn't sure about), and I'll need to attach the event handler on the inputField, not the form (see next-to-last paragraph).  But this doesn't feel like a 'standard' VF design; I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this provided by the platform.  If I can't find one, this will be it.